# X509Certificate and XmlDsig

Tags: c#, x509certificate, signature, xml-signature

I need, in C# (4.0), to sign an XML (XMLDSig Envelope) using a X509Certificate (a .p7b file provided by the one which should verify the signature)
I do not have experience in security, my knowledge stops to some basic concepts about cryptography .

Here is what i have done:

1) I have installed the certificate in: Certificates - Current User - Trusted Root Certification.

2) from .net i succesfully loaded the certificate with this code:

```
X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreName.Root, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
try
{
    store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
    X509Certificate2Collection certs = store.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindBySubjectName, certName, false);
    if (certs.Count == 0)
        return null;

    return certs[0];
}
finally
{
    store.Close();
}
```

3) I tried to use the public key of the certificate to create a signature with the following code;

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.PreserveWhitespace = true;
var reader = new StringReader(xml);
doc.Load(reader);
var signedXml = new SignedXml(doc);
X509Certificate2 certificate = this.GetCertificateFromStore(certName); // the previous code
signedXml.SigningKey = (RSACryptoServiceProvider)certificate.PublicKey.Key;
var reference = new Reference();
reference.Uri = "";
XmlDsigEnvelopedSignatureTransform env = new XmlDsigEnvelopedSignatureTransform();
reference.AddTransform(env);
signedXml.AddReference(reference);
signedXml.ComputeSignature(); //  exception!!!
var element = signedXml.GetXml();
doc.AppendChild(doc.ImportNode(element, true));
```

but when computing the signature i get an exception: "Object contains only the public half of a key pair. A private key must also be provided."

I checked the property HasPrivateKey in the certificate and it is false. 
My (basic) understanding is that I should not have the private key and I should be able to create a signature using the public key.

What I'm missing ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.p7b stands for PKCS#7 format which doesn't normally contain a private key. When you sign the document, you prove it's authenticity by applying a private key, which belongs to you and which you must keep secret. So it's very unlikely that anyone (besides probably your network administrator or sometimes a bank) would give you *your* private key.

Comment: In my case, I have an application that need to send xml to a customer service. I suppose that the customer would like to know that the sender (me) can be trusted (or maybe others applications). They gave me a .p7b to be used to sign the xml. Do you you think i need to ask for a privatekey (a key that the customer could share with trusted partners) or is it possible to obtain the same task with only the public key ?

Comment: @SkyG You must have your own certificate with a private key AND give this certificate (without a private key of course) to the customer. If the customer gave you it's certificate and asked you to sign your data using this certificate, this can mean one of the following: (a) the customer doesn't understand how PKI works, or (b) the customer meant that you needed to *encrypt* the data (and this again says that the customer is not competent in security). more...

Comment: @SkyG To verify that the certificate you used for signing belongs to you the customer validates the certificate. This is a complex procedure, automated in most software. It works when your certificate is signed by some well-known certificate authority. Eg. if you go to http://www.globalsign.com/document-security-compliance/adobe-cds/ and purchase PDF signing certificate, customer's Adobe Reader will validate this certificate properly automatically. The same works with XML.

Comment: Thanks Eugene, I'll then start reading more about PKI :).  I would like to vote up the answer but I still not have enough points to do it.

Answer (score 2):

If you were to create a digital signature for your content, your will encrypt the digest of this content with your Private Key and send your orignal content + your signature to the recepient.

Verification phase:
The verifier, will decrypt your signature using your public key, and get hash H1. Then the orignal content is hashed by recepient to H1.
Recepient verifies if H1 equals to H2, if not signature verification fails.